# Solving nonlinear 2-variable recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, triangular-numbers

How does one solve the recurrence relation
$a(n,k) = a(n-1,k) +\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n-2, 1 \leq j \leq k-1}a(i,j)a(n-1-i,k-j) +a(n-1,k-1)$?

With initial conditions $a(1,1) = 1$ and $a(n,k) = 0$ for all $\lbrace (n,k): n < k \text{ or } n \leq 0 \text{ or } k \leq 0 \rbrace$, I computed the first few rows of the triangle and guessed (It was of great help to notice $a(n,2) = n(n-1)/2$, OEIS  confirmed the hunch for larger $k$) the solution to be $a(n,k) = \binom{n}{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{1}{k}$.  Given the guess, it is possible to verify the recursion holds.

I wanted to ask: is there a general way for solving this  type of recurrence relation that does not involve 'guessing and working backwards'?

Comment: Define 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A(x,y)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a(n,m) x^n y^m.
\end{eqnarray*}
& define 
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_m(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  a(n,m) x^n 
\end{eqnarray*}
See what your recurrence formula gives for these functions ... Also try writing out the first few values of $a(n,m)$ and see if OEIS has this grid of numbers ... indeed add these values into your question & I will see if I recognise them ... I would guess they might be close to the Naryana numbers. ... Let me know how you get on $\ddot \smile$

Comment: $a(n,k)$ are the Narayana numbers, as defined in Wiki.

Comment: In which case, problem solved ... have a good look here https://oeis.org/A001263 as well as wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narayana_number